# Stack of strings in c

Tags: c

This program is working, but only with numbers. I need it to work with strings. I have no idea how to do this. Nothing is working. I'm asking for some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 20

struct stack            
{
    int stk[MAXSIZE];
    int top;
};

typedef struct stack STACK;
STACK s;

void push (void);
void display (void);

void main()
{
    int choice;
    int option = 1;
    s.top = -1;

    while (option)
    {
        printf ("\nNacisnij 1 aby wprowadzic elemnt do stosu\n"); //press 1 to push on stack
        printf ("Nacisnij 2 aby wyswietlic stan stosu\n"); //press 2 to display stack
        printf ("Nacisnij 3 aby zakonczyc\n\n"); //press 3 to exit
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1: 
                push();
                break;
            case 2:
                display();
                break;
            case 3:
                return;
        }
        fflush (stdin);
    }
}

void push()
{
    int num;
    if (s.top == (MAXSIZE - 1))
    {
        printf ("Stos jest pelen\n");// stack is full
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("\nWprowadz element\n");// enter element
        scanf("%d", &num);
        s.top = s.top + 1;
        s.stk[s.top] = num;
    }
    return;
}

void display()
{
    int i;
    if (s.top == -1)
    {
        printf ("Stos jest pusty\n"); //stack is empty
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("\nStan stosu\n"); //state of the stack
        for (i = s.top; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            printf ("%d\n", s.stk[i]);
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Comment: Please intend your code and give us an actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `int stk[MAXSIZE];` as a character array to make it work for strings and you need to change this line to read a string `scanf ("%d", &num);` So the changes you need are

```
struct stack            
{
    char stk[MAXSIZE][MAX_STR_LEN];// You have to define MAX_STR_LEN to a value you desire
    int top;
};
```

Change the following code

```
scanf ("%d", &num);
s.top = s.top + 1;
s.stk[s.top] = num;
```

to

```
s.top = s.top + 1;
scanf ("%s", s.stk[s.top]);
```